# Plotly: How to update figure with multiple dependent traces using updatemenus?

Tags: python, plot, plotly, regression, visualization

I am updating a scatter plot using updatemenus that take as arguments the fields I want to update:

```
dict(label = category,
      method = 'update',
      args = [dict(x=[df[(df['cat_name'] == category) & (df['cat_level'] == cat_level)]['value']], 
                        y=[df[(df['cat_name'] == category) & (df['cat_level'] == cat_level)]['count']],
                        meta = [["Category:" + category]]
                                          )])
```

I have a second trace that I’m adding (it’s a best fit line), that I would like to have update as the menu choice change (when the user selects a menu category the visual updates with that category data - therefore the line of best fit should change).

Is there a smart way to construct this?

Comment: Do you mind to provide a full [mcve](/help/mcve)?

Comment: @guyts How did my suggestion work out for you?

Comment: @vestland haven't actually attempted it yet - once i do , I'll update and accept answer here if it worked :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your source is a pandas dataframe, the key here is to build a linear model for each column in its own dataframe, and then add a dropdownmenu with a button for each source column and associated linear model using a loop like this:

```
for col in df.columns:
    buttons.append(dict(method='restyle',
                        label=col,
                        visible=True,
                        args=[{'y':[df[col], df_reg[col+'_model']],
                               'x':[df.index],
                               'type':'scatter'}],
                        )
                  )
```

**Plot 1:** Column A and associated linear model:

[image]

**Plot 2:** Column B and associated linear model:

[image]

**Complete code with reproducible data sample:**

```
# imports
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
from datetime import datetime
# conda install -c anaconda scikit-learn
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression #(conda install -c anaconda scikit-learn)

# data sample
nperiods=200
np.random.seed(123)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(-10,12,size=(nperiods, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
datelist = pd.date_range(datetime(2020, 1, 1).strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), periods=nperiods).tolist()
df['dates'] = datelist 
df = df.set_index(['dates'])
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df.iloc[0]=0
df=df.cumsum()

# build dataframe df_reg with linear models using sklearn
# for each column in df
df_reg = pd.DataFrame()
# regression
for col in df:
    #print(col)
    reg = LinearRegression().fit(np.vstack(np.arange(0, len(df))), df[col].values)
    df_reg[col+'_model'] = reg.predict(np.vstack(np.arange(0, len(df))))


#plotly
fig=go.Figure()

# set up one trace for source data in df
# and one trace for each linear model in df_reg
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df.index,
                             y=df[df.columns[0]],
                             visible=True))

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df.index,
                             y=df_reg[df_reg.columns[0]],
                             visible=True))
# Define updatemenus
updatemenu=[]
buttons=[]

# add buttons to select column in df
# and the associated linear model in df_reg
for col in df.columns:
    buttons.append(dict(method='restyle',
                        label=col,
                        visible=True,
                        args=[{'y':[df[col], df_reg[col+'_model']],
                               'x':[df.index],
                               'type':'scatter'}],
                        )
                  )

# some adjustments to the updatemenus
updatemenu=[]
your_menu=dict()
updatemenu.append(your_menu)

updatemenu[0]['buttons']=buttons
updatemenu[0]['direction']='down'
updatemenu[0]['showactive']=True

# add dropdown menus to the figure
fig.update_layout(showlegend=False, updatemenus=updatemenu)
fig.show()
```